# Java Stream: sorting by ZoneDateTime field

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I want to sort a list in reverse order by ZoneDateTime field, limit count by 20

```
    public class VisitViewDTO implements Serializable {
      private ZonedDateTime visitDate;
      private int count;

      public ZonedDateTime getVisitDate() {
        return visitDate;
    }
}
```

.....

```
List<VisitViewDTO> visitViewDTOList;

visitViewDTOList.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(VisitViewDTO::getVisitDate).reversed()).limit(20).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But got NPE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.time.chrono.ChronoZonedDateTime.compareTo(ChronoZonedDateTime.java:570)
    at java.time.chrono.ChronoZonedDateTime.compareTo(ChronoZonedDateTime.java:121)
    at java.util.Comparator.lambda$comparing$77a9974f$1(Comparator.java:469)
    at java.util.Collections$ReverseComparator2.compare(Collections.java:5178)
    at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:356)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:220)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1512)
```

Comment: It seems that `visitDate` in some of your dto objects is null.

Comment: If @michalk is correct (sounds likely), you need a null tolerant comparator. Look up `Comparator.nullsFirst` and `Comparator.nullsLast`.

Comment: Good point . I checked - all objects have not-null visitDate

Comment: A minimal,complete and verifiable example, please? Asking because if `visitDate` is never null, I can't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: Well, Ole V.V.
If the given code is correct, I will check it in other places.

Comment: Yes , you were right. In some other place i added object to list  with null visitDate. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that visitDate in some of your dto objects was null. One solution is to filter out null elements :

```
visitViewDTOList.stream()
                .filter(visitViewDTO -> visitViewDTO.getVisitDate() != null)
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(VisitViewDTO::getVisitDate).reversed())
                .limit(20)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or use comparator which will deal with nulls first or last - [nullsFirst](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsFirst-java.util.Comparator-) and [nullsLast](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsLast-java.util.Comparator-)

```
visitViewDTOList.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(VisitViewDTO::getVisitDate, Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.reverseOrder())))
                .limit(20)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

As correctly pointed out by michalk, there can be some elements with `visitDate=null`which may cause `NullPointerException` 
So you may want to filter non null values,

```
 visitViewDTOList.stream().filter(ele-> Objects.nonNull(ele.getVisitDate()))
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(VisitViewDTO::getVisitDate).reversed())
                .limit(20).collect(Collectors.toList());
```